# Merge each value in an array to each value in another array - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays

```
let arr1 = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}]
let arr2 = [{c: 5}, {c: 6}]
```

I am trying to create a new array such that each value in arr1 is mapped to each value in arr2. Something like this,

```
[1-2-5, 1-2-6, 3-4-5, 3-4,6]
```

I know that this can be done using two for loops. One to loop on arr1 and a nested for loop that loops over arr2. But I am looking for a cheap and efficient method to do it. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: It won't get any cheaper than a loop.

Comment: It's always going to be two loops... `const result = arr1.flatMap((o) => arr2.map((_o) => ({ ...o, ..._o })));`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map()` to achieve this.

```js
let arr1 = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}]
let arr2 = [{c: 5}, {c: 6}]

const result = arr1.flatMap((x) => {
  return arr2.map((y) => `${x.a}-${x.b}-${y.c}`);
});

console.log(result);
```

Because you can't use `-` in a number, storing the values in separate arrays would be an option.

```js
let arr1 = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}]
let arr2 = [{c: 5}, {c: 6}]

const result = arr1.flatMap((x) => {
  return arr2.map((y) => [x.a, x.b, y.c]);
});

console.log(result);
```